# Rails: validating locked checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have, in my form, a checkbox that set a boolean true or false (default => false)

I fixed everything to let the user edit the form anytime, but, if anyone mark the checkbox once, that can never be undone.

i have a partial solution which is block the check box and i did this by doing:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :split, "Item split " %><br>
  <% if ! f.object.split or @item.new_record? %>
    <%= f.check_box :split %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.check_box :split, :disabled => true %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this works great, but i fell like i really should validate this thing, because if something set this value from true to false, it could break the entire database.

How do i validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the value from true to false will break the entire database, then you shouldn't allow it to even reach the database.

Add this code to your `item.rb` model:

```
def split=(boolean)
  if self.split
    self[:split] = true
  else
    self[:split] = boolean
  end
end
```

You can also validate in the controller before it even reaches the model. To do so, add this to your controller's update action before it saves:

```
def update
  # This line will ensure that :split stays true if it was true before
  params[:item][:split] = true if @item.split

  # ... other original code
end
```

These code camples will still allow the checkbox to be set TO true FROM false, but not the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, Whats the diference of doing  "self[:fracionado] = true" and self.fracionado = true?

Comment: They are basically the same, however, if you call `self.fracionado` inside of the `frecionado` method, it will cause a loop error. Therefore, in this situation, you would want to use `self[:fracionado]`